# underscore.js each, iterator reference error

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore.js templating to iterate over an object

```
var list = "<% _.each(resgistrations, function(resgistration) { %> <tr><td><%= i %></td><td><%= resgistration %></td></tr> <% }, i); %>";
```

I don't understand why `i` won't work as my iterator. I get a reference error `i is not defined`. This seems like it's straight out of [the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#each) for `_.each`

Comment: You are not creating the index parameter; of course `i` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the second parameter, the iterator `i`.
Try this:

```
var list = "<% _.each(resgistrations, function(resgistration, i) { %> <%= i %><%= resgistration %> <% }); %>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified the first parameter as `registration` for the iterator value, and didn't assign a second parameter for the index — or rather, you passed it in the wrong place. The fixed code would be:

```
var list = "<% _.each(resgistrations, function(resgistration, i) { %> <tr><td><%= i %></td><td><%= resgistration %></td></tr> <% }); %>";
```